# Inserting code with some google map stuff in a new window with javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm basically creating a new page with a google map and title based on the button clicked. The html in the newhtml variable works if copy/pasted into an html file, but not with document.write() for some reason. I know the problem has something to do the last script in the newhtml variable. Does anyone have an idea why it will not work?

test.js

```js
function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

open_event_test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Bee Map 2nd Level</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Bee Map Proof-of-Concept</h1>

<h3>Carbon County</h3>
<button onclick="myFunction('Bombus balteatus')"><em>Bombus balteatus</em> Dahlbom</button>

<button onClick="myFunction('Bombus auricomus')"><em>Bombus auricomus</em> (Robertson)</button>

<script>
function myFunction(species) 
{
    var newhtml = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta charset="utf-8"><head><script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"><\/script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"><\/script><title>'+species+'<\/title><style>#map-canvas{width:400px;height:300px;}</style><\/head><body><h1><em>'+species+'</em> in County</h1><div id="map-canvas"></div><div id="loc_info"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"><\/script><\/body><\/html>';
 console.log(newhtml);
 var newWindow = window.open(species, '_blank');
 newWindow.document.write(newhtml);
 
 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

seem you have a slash in the wrong place

```
var newhtml = '<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html><meta charset="utf-8">
    <head><script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">

 ******
   <\/script>
 ********
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"><\/script><title>'+species+'</title><style>#map-canvas{width:400px;height:300px;}</style></head><body><h1><em>'+species+'</em> in County</h1><div id="map-canvas"></div><div id="loc_info"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="species_county_map.js"><\/script></body></html>';
```

Comment: The code in the variable when printed to the console is valid, the backslash is an escape for the script tag, otherwise the first </script> would prematurely close the script tag around myFunction()

Comment: This is only for the script tag or also for the style, title,, because these other don't have the escape backslash..

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet works on my end as it opens a new window with the species and country, but there's no Map displayed since you've not yet implemented it (the question may not have something to do with Maps itself).

I think its best for you to follow the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) of the Google Maps API for JavaScript. When the page is instantiated, call a JS function that will instantiate the Map object into the page.

Hope this helps!